# Keeping a Div Visible or Hidden after postback in aspx using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a div that can be open like on this picture with the button on the top right corner
[image: Div open]

Or it can be closed like on this picture
[[image: Div Closed]]

The problem is when I click on the editing pen in my `GridView` as you can see on the picture there is a postback causing the div to open again since it is the default value on page load.

Here is my pageLoad function in aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showAndHideOnPageLoad", "InitalShowAndHide();", true);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showAndHideOnPageLoad", "InitalShowAndHide();", true);

    }
}
```

And here is the JavaScript for the hide and show div

```
function showAllFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("PageContent_btnExpandMenu");
    var z = document.getElementById("PageContent_btnCollapseMenu");
    var x = document.getElementById("PageContent_secondMenuContent");
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "block";
}
function hideAllFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("PageContent_btnExpandMenu");
    var z = document.getElementById("PageContent_btnCollapseMenu");
    var x = document.getElementById("PageContent_secondMenuContent");
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "none";
}
```

Here are the important elements of the aspx page.

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCollapseMenu" ImageUrl="~/images/minimize.png" runat="server"  Width="20px" Height="20px"  OnClientClick="hideAllFunction(); return false;" CssClass="second-menu-icon"/>     
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnExpandMenu" ImageUrl="~/images/maximize.png" runat="server"  Width="20px" Height="20px"  OnClientClick="showAllFunction(); return false;" CssClass="second-menu-icon"/>  

  <div ID="secondMenuContent" class="second-menu-show-style" runat="server">
```

My question is how can I keep it hidden or visible depending on the user choice after a postback is made. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store hide/show value in in hidden field. and use that hidden field value to show/hide div. that will resolve your issue.

```
// 0 for hide
<asp:HiddenFieldID="hdnfldCurrentDateTime" value="0" runat="server" />  

function showAllFunction() {
   //access the value of hidden field or store value in hidden field and write logic for hide/show
}
```

Comment: I know very little of javascript. Could you show me how to do it in my situation were there are two buttons one for hide and one for show and how to do it. It would be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, thank you I figured it out by myself thanks to you.